# Embed gets sent more than once. How do I make it send only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to change the color of an embed based on the number it rolled. It works, but sometimes the embed gets sent multiple times. I don't want that.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    function roll(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    };

    if (roll(3) === 0) {
        const e = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Test")
            .setColor("#ff00a0")
            .setDescription('I'm just testing stuff at the moment :)');
        
        var r = roll(999);
        console.log(r);

        if (r <= 305) {
            const ea = new Discord.MessageEmbed(e).setColor("ORANGE");
            message.channel.send(ea);

        } else if (r >= 306 && r <= 406) {
            const es = new Discord.MessageEmbed(e).setColor("GREEN");
            message.channel.send(es);

        } else if (r >= 600 && r <= 610) {
            const ess = new Discord.MessageEmbed(e).setColor("PURPLE");
            message.channel.send(ess);

        } else if (r == 500 || r == 996 || r == 997 || r == 998 || r == 999) {
            const esss = new Discord.MessageEmbed(e).setColor("BLUE");
            message.channel.send(esss);

        } else {
            message.channel.send(e);
        };
    };
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new embed every time, you can just modify the old one: `e.setColor('color')`. Also, when the message gets sent multiple times, do they share the same color?

Comment: @Lioness100 They share the same color if the condition is met. It basically rolls more than once.

Comment: And it only happens sometimes?

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes only sometimes. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/DICLUZl.jpg) is what I mean by sometimes.